# Sorting array from CSV file

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, sorting, csv

I have a CSV-file, that I've parsed into my xcode project.

The CSV-file is in randomly sorting order, and I want the lowest number to be first.

I keep getting a warning that says "incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSMutableArray *' from 'NSArray *'? I think this has something to do with that I'm trying to sort a regular array and a mutable array?
This is my code for parsing the CSV file:

```
NSString *hejhej = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"2" ofType:@"csv"];
NSString *nyt = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:hejhej encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSString *nytnyt = [nyt stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];


NSMutableArray *row= [[nytnyt componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n,"]mutableCopy];
NSMutableArray *data = [NSMutableArray array];
for(NSString *line in row){
    NSMutableArray *points = [[line componentsSeparatedByString:@","] mutableCopy];
```

my file look like this when i drag and drop it into my project (this is just test data):

```
"""00.52.36"",""5"""
,"""01.22.55"",""54"""
,"""01.14.54"",""8"""
,"""02.43.54"",""32"""
,"""03.43.02"",""11"""
,"""03.14.11"",""1"""
,"""06.23.32"",""15"""
,"""06.54.43"",""7"""
,"""07.32.12"",""2"""
,"""07.45.45"",""22"""
,"""08.11.22"",""43"""
,"""08.45.43"",""9"""
,"""09.00.11"",""222"""
,"""09.44.32"",""43"""
,"""10.21.34"",""321"""
,"""10.44.22"",""55"""
,"""11.01.02"",""21"""
```

I want to sort it by the lowest value first. So it should switch row 2 and 3, and 5 and 6 .

I'm using this code to sort it, but it doesn't work?

```
NSSortDescriptor *sd = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:nil ascending:YES];
points = [points sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: @[sd]];
```

Comment: `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors` returns an `NSArray*`, and you assign it to `points`, which is a `NSMutableArray*`. That's why you get a warning. For instance if later you tried to call `addObject:` on `points`, assuming, that it is a mutable array, you would get a runtime error, since, despite the fact that `points` is declared as mutable, in reality it is an immutable array.

Answer (score 0):

@Try This  csv parsing example projects

https://github.com/ha-minh-vuong/CSVParser

https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser